# SimpleXML Parsing Feed with children

Tags: php, rss

I've seen different versions of this question asked but nothing that specifically answered mine.

I'm trying to parse [this](http://www.serverstrategies.com/rss.php?sid=WV87&len=20&rand=0&drop_1=) Rss feed that pulls the results from a search on a Pet adoption site and turns it into a RSS/Atom feed.

```
<?php
//RSS solution
$feed = simplexml_load_file('http://www.serverstrategies.com/rss.php?sid=WV87&len=20&rand=0&drop_1=');
$children = $feed->children('http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
echo $children->entry[1]->item[0]->title;
?>
```

I've tried a lot of different variations of this but I've yet to get anything to print out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this solution will be helpful in getting all the `titles` and `descriptions`.

```
<?php

$feed = simplexml_load_file('http://www.serverstrategies.com/rss.php?sid=WV87&len=20&rand=0&drop_1=');

$result=array();
foreach($feed->channel->item as $node)
{
     $result[]=array("title"=>(string)$node->title,
         "description"=>  strip_tags((string)$node->description));
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: I'm really trying to come up with a solution that I'm able to use to grab all the attributes of each "item" so I can theme how it looks on a webpage. For example, grab the img, title, and description of each into a variable. Is there a better way to do this with that in mind?

Comment: @Trebax do you want to gather all title, description in an array? is it write?

Comment: Perfect I can go from there, I've been trying random stuff for a few hours so this is a big help!